# Changing python immutable type while iterating through a mutable container such as list

Tags: python, types, iteration, immutability

I am wondering what is the most pythonic way to do the following and have it work:

```
strings = ['a','b']

for s in strings:  
    s = s+'c'
```

obviously this doesn't work in python but the result that I want to acheive is
strings = ['ac','bc']
Whats the most pythonic way to achieve this kind of result?

Thanks for the great answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
strings = ['a', 'b']
strings = [s + 'c' for s in strings]
```

Comment: or `strings[:] = ..` to change the existing list

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension to create a list that has these values: `[s + 'c' for s in strings]`. You *can* modify the list in-place like this:

```
for i, s in enumerate(strings):
    strings[i] = s + 'c'
```

But I found that quite often, in-place modification is not needed. Look at your code to see if this applies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map function for that.

```
strings = ['a', 'b']
strings = map(lambda s: s + 'c', strings)
```

Comment: Make sure you grab the return value of `map`.